# Encrypted Data to Decimal

Tags: mysql, encryption, decimal

```
SELECT AES_ENCRYPT(12.21, UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134'));
```

How can i convert the encrypted data above to be stored in column DECIMAL(15,2)?

Comment: Any suggestions of encryption function that results int or decimal that can be stored on the said column type.

Comment: Are you interested in a 1-way encryption function (once encrypted, you cannot decrypt and get the original value) ?

Comment: Try: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oYnrx5jkAnSqNCqzYL26qW/0

Comment: Is there any way, that can be decrypt also

Comment: I have something working, but it is `DECIMAL(65)`; the reason being AES encryption does convert into a binary string using mostly multibyte characters. Check: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oYnrx5jkAnSqNCqzYL26qW/1 

If it works for you, I will then figure out the reverse method to decrypt back.

Comment: This can be done, but it is called Format Preserving Encryption or FPE, and it is far from easy to apply - and you'd have to map it to/from DECIMAL(15,2) as well. It will also generate identical ciphertext for identical input.

Comment: i'm not familiar with that, can you elaborate or give me some examples, thanks

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya thanks for the encryption, can you help me for the decryption.

Comment: @Allen can do, but why do you want to go from a 16 byte binary to 65+ bytes decimal form ? You will be consuming more than 4 times space

Comment: most of my tables having a column DECIMAL(15,2) so it will take time to change table structure

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya but if there's no way for that format, i will be using your idea, so can you help me for the decryption?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I hope it can hold DECIMAL(15,6)

Comment: Why? DECIMAL is a poor choice for an encrypted value, and DECIMAL with decimal places is meaningless. Encrypted values don't have decimal palces.

Answer (score 1):

Do you *know* that the value (such as `12.21`) will *always* fit in `DECIMAL(15,2)`?

If so, I don't see what the problem is.

`AES_ENCRYPT(12.21, UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134'))` generates some gibberish.  Store that into a `BLOB` or `VARBINARY(..)` of suitable size.  Then

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(the_blob, UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134'))
```

will generate the string `12.21`.  If you `INSERT` that string into a `DECIMAL(15,2)`, it should work fine.

If you store into `DECIMAL(65)`, it will drop the decimal parts and give you a value of `12` (which is not the same as 12.21).

If you store into `DECIMAL(15,6)`, the number will the same (except for four trailing zeros).  But watch out, that has room for only 9 digits before the decimal point.  Etc.

Test case:

```
mysql> SELECT AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT(12.21,
                  UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134')),
                  UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134'));
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| AES_DECRYPT(AES_ENCRYPT(12.21, UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134')), UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134')) |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 12.21                                                                                                         |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Note that the encrypted value is some multiple of 16 bytes:

```
mysql> SELECT LENGTH(AES_ENCRYPT(12.21, UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134')));+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| LENGTH(AES_ENCRYPT(12.21, UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134'))) |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                16 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| LENGTH(AES_ENCRYPT(1234567890.123456789, UNHEX('6E6F727468656173744032303134'))) |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                               32 |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```